# Probability and statistics of biased coin

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a biased coin, with probabilities p of coming up heads and $q = 1 -p$
of coming up tails on any given toss, but we are not given what $p$ or $q$ are. We know
from class that the expected value of the number of heads in $n$ tosses is $E(X) = np$. If we
repeatedly flip the coin and record the results, the number of heads that actually turn up,
call it $\hat E$, can be divided by the number of tosses, $n$, to give an estimate, $p = \frac{\hat E}n$ , of $p$.

The problem is that we're likely to have to be pretty lucky for $\hat{p} = p$, so the real question
is how likely it is that $\hat{p}$ is close to $p$. (This sort of thing is what statistics is all about:
trying to infer from actual data what is really true and then estimate the likelihood that
what is inferred is close to reality.)
Let us suppose, for the sake of argument, that we know that $0.5\le p\le 0.6$ (so
$0.4 \le q = 1 -p\le 0.5$) for our biased coin and that we have the time and patience to toss it any finite number of times $n$ that we want.
 Further, let us suppose that we desire to get
an estimate of $p$ that is within $5\%$ of the real value, i.e. $0.95p\le \hat{p}\le 1:05p$.

1. How many times do we need to toss the coin, keeping track of the number of tosses
   and the number of success, to ensure that $P( 0.95p\le \hat{p}\le 1.05 p)\ge  0.95$? Please justify
   your answer as fully as you can. [10]
   Note: That is, what does $n$ have to be to ensure that the probability that $\hat{p}$ is within $5\%$
   of $p$ is at least $0.95$?

Answer (score 1):

Start with assuming that the true value is $p=0.6$, for example and assume you know $n$.
What is $P(0.95\cdot0.6\cdot n\le \hat E\le 1.05\cdot0.6\cdot n)$?
How big must $n$ be to make this at least $0.95$?

Next assume that the true value is $p=0.5$, for example and assume you know $n$.
What is $P(0.95\cdot0.5\cdot n\le \hat E\le 1.05\cdot0.5\cdot n)$?
How big must $n$ be to make this at least $0.95$?

What happens if the true value of $p$ is somewhere between $0.5$ and $0.6$? Can we perhaps conclude that the values of $n$ that work for *both* of the extreme cases also work here?

Comment: So I just assume the value of n because I do not understand how to find the value of n I know it means that it is the number of trials. I am just confused I think.

Answer (score -1):

For $\varepsilon=0.05$ solve for $n$

$$\sum_{k={\lceil}pn(1-\varepsilon){\rceil}}^{{\lfloor}pn(1+\varepsilon){\rfloor}}{{n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}>1-\varepsilon$$

I do not think it is tractable to find an $n$ in terms of arbitrary $p,\varepsilon$. Computing some bounds or parametric models on bounds can be possible.